# c++ memory leak in queue initialization

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, gdb, queue, valgrind

Recently my company migrated to new servers and this program no longer worked correctly. It compiles ok, but when running we get errors and crashes while initializing a queue. Using valgrind I can see memory leaks in the queue library. the code is much bigger but it would have been hard to put it all in here, so I cut as much as I thought reasonable. I think there might be a problem I just can't see concerning versions or something, can anyone suggest hints/help?

```
typedef  unsigned char     byte;
typedef  unsigned char     boolean;

typedef  unsigned int      uint32;
typedef  unsigned short    uint16;
typedef  unsigned char     uint8;

typedef  signed long int   int32;       /* Signed 32 bit value */
typedef  signed short      int16;       /* Signed 16 bit value */
typedef  signed char       int8;        /* Signed 8  bit value */
```

Just some type defs so the next part doesn't confuse

```
struct MIPMsg
{
    byte           msg[1024];
    uint32         msglen;
    uint32         ipaddr;
    ushort         sin_port;
    uint32         MNHomeAddr;
    struct timeval ts;
    MIPMsg() : msglen(0), ipaddr(0), sin_port(0) , MNHomeAddr(0)
    {
            memset( msg, '\0', sizeof(msg) );
    }
};

class MIPMsgQueue {
public:
    MIPMsgQueue();
    ~MIPMsgQueue();


private:
    queue<MIPMsg*>    mQueue_;
};
```

That's the h cut h file, and here's the cut cpp file.

```
MIPMsgQueue() :: MIPMsgQueue() : mQueue_()
{
}
```

and here's the valgrind snippet.

```
==25753==    at 0x4A0666E: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:220)
==25753==    by 0x4045C6: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<MIPMsg**>::allocate(unsigned long,        void const*) (new_allocator.h:88)
==25753==    by 0x4045F9: std::_Deque_base<MIPMsg*, std::allocator<MIPMsg*>    >::_M_allocate_map(unsigned long) (stl_deque.h:424)
==25753==    by 0x404B23: std::_Deque_base<MIPMsg*, std::allocator<MIPMsg*> >::_M_initialize_map(unsigned long) (stl_deque.h:471)
==25753==    by 0x404C70: std::_Deque_base<MIPMsg*, std::allocator<MIPMsg*> >::_Deque_base(std::allocator<MIPMsg*> const&, unsigned long) (stl_deque.h:368)
==25753==    by 0x404D0D: std::deque<MIPMsg*, std::allocator<MIPMsg*> >::deque(std::deque<MIPMsg*, std::allocator<MIPMsg*> > const&) (stl_deque.h:690)
==25753==    by 0x404E20: std::queue<MIPMsg*, std::deque<MIPMsg*, std::allocator<MIPMsg*> > >::queue(std::deque<MIPMsg*, std::allocator<MIPMsg*> > const&) (stl_queue.h:146)
==25753==    by 0x4033E2: MIPMsgQueue::MIPMsgQueue() (MIPMsgQueue.cpp:5)
```

also here's the gdb error code

```
 munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000621770 ***
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: replace your queue with the STL queue and it is far more likely to work, also I know you don't wanna redo all ur code but I notice your using a lot of naked pointers, wrap them in smart pointers to take advantage of RAII

Comment: also instead of showing us the typedefs, leave them out and do the replacement yourself so we have to read less

Comment: @aaronman what says queue isnt std::queue? infact, i'd say the error message indicate it is, as std::queue by default uses std::deque under the hood.

Comment: @aaronman MiqMsgQueue has a member queue<MIPMsg*>

Comment: @Borgleader my other point about naked pointers still applies

Comment: Looking at the valgrind output, I don't see the queue leaking, I see MIPMsgQueue's constructor leaking. Most likely its constructor was never called. Is that the only error valgrind is reporting?

Comment: I see a destructor, but no copy constructor or assignment operator. Looks like a Rule of Three violation.

Comment: You would probably be shocked to see that it is *very* likely this will *work* if you simply use `std::queue<MIPMsg>`. Nothing in that object class doesn't support value-copying, so unless you on some imbedded system with a ridiculously low memory limit and every byte is priceless, make your life easier and just use a value-based queue.

Comment: Take a look at stdint.h, too. It contains typedefs for sized integer types where you're not at the mercy of the compiler. For example, you assume that a `long` is 32 bits, which is wrong on many platforms. uint32_t from stdint.h is exactly 32 bits though, which is guaranteed. That said, there are namespaces to replace prefixes like "MIP" and `typedef unsigned char boolean` is a complete anachronism (or merits proper explanation).

Answer (score 0):

> Using valgrind I can see memory leaks in the queue library

Memory leaks do not (usually) lead to crashes. This error:

> munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000621770 ***

Implies heap corruption, possibly due to calling `delete` on a global variable. Ignore the memory leaks, and look for *other* valgrind errors (and `invalid free/delete` in particular).

Answer (score 0):

You have said *this program no longer worked correctly*, which means you don't change any code?If so, I suggest that you check the difference before and after, such as compilation condition or other change.

More details is provided would be help.